# Java update page content with Spring from server side

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In studing purposes I'm interested in makind my own app for showing some data on web page . But the problem is, that this data should be update every 2 minutes. I know I can make some polling, but is there a way to make server do data collecting every 2 minutes and sending it to web page which will refresh table with data.

Interested in Java with Spring solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for such updating of client there are 2 main ways:

- open a socket between the client and the server, this socket acts as a 2-way data send/receive
- server-sent-events a pooling protocol over http the client ask the server for new data, you can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events)

each method has its pro and cons, and you should decide base on your use case

**socket** is very fast but require allocation of resources e.g the server need to listen to incoming traffic so a process need to maintain this socket and a port on the machine is allocated, this will not scale well...
also socket is a messages (strings) transmission, and one need to implement a protocol (or use existing)

**server-sent-events** based http so the whole protocol is build and very easy to use, not as fast as socket, very efficient in resource allocation, the client trigger communication with the server, so the server don't need to listen especially for this client and can handle other requests

both are very easily implemented and integrated with spring